# How can I access a user's ID on another site (eg. SU) if I have their ID from another site (eg. SO)?

Tags: support, users, api-v2.2, sites

If I have the ID of a user from *any* site, how can I get that's user's ID for a site I specify?

Eg. If someone's ID was `10349` on Super User, how could I get `10349`'s id on Stack Overflow?

I know I'd be able to use [`associated_users`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users), but that's only if I have the user's **main SE profile's ID**, right?

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use [the `/users/{ids}` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids) to get `account_id`.
2. Then pass the `account_id` to [`/users/{ids}/associated`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users).

Note that `account_id` is exactly the kind of information that should be heavily cached by your script/app. (Hint, hint; wink, wink; nudge, nudge. (^_^) )

**For example:**

```
/2.2/users/10349?site=superuser&filter=!T6o*9deY.2ZD3-(n4f
```

[Returns:](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=10349&filter=!T6o*9deY.2ZD3-%28n4f&site=superuser&run=true)

```
{
  "account_id": 1605,
  "reputation": 178,
  "user_id": 10349,
  "display_name": "On Freund"
}
```

Then:

```
/2.2/users/1605/associated?filter=!--KJWbRC6EPM
```

[Returns:](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=1605&filter=!--KJWbRC6EPM&run=true)

```
{
  "question_count": 5,
  "answer_count": 117,
  "last_access_date": 1431898687,
  "creation_date": 1219247035,
  "account_id": 1605,
  "reputation": 3612,
  "user_id": 2150,
  "site_url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
  "site_name": "Stack Overflow"
},
{
  "question_count": 2,
  "answer_count": 1,
  "last_access_date": 1428968656,
  "creation_date": 1252397718,
  "account_id": 1605,
  "reputation": 178,
  "user_id": 10349,
  "site_url": "http://superuser.com",
  "site_name": "Super User"
}
```